# Clustered bar chart on R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a clustered bar chart on R showing the types of species distributed over a number of years. The code i used was:

```
Fish<- read.table( header=TRUE, text="Mbio$Date, Mbio$Roach,Mbio$Green.sunfish,
Mbio$Sucker, Mbio$Rainbow.trout, Mbio$Squawfish, Mbio$Mosquito.fish")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Fish, aes(factor(Mbio$Date), Mbio$Roach,Mbio$Green.sunfish, Mbio$Sucker, Mbio$Rainbow.trout, Mbio$Squawfish, Mbio$Mosquito.fish)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

This gave a graph like this:

[image: Cluster Graph: Click to View]

However this is not giving me the graph I want: It needs to show the number of each of the fish species across all the years.

I would like it to look like this image. Please assist me with this, thank you.
[image: Correct graph:Click to view]

Comment: use `dput(Mbio)` and paste those results in here instead. by in here i mean edit your question and don't paste it in the comments

Answer (score 2):

## Creating data and making bar plots

```
column1 <- c(rep("1984", 3), rep("1985", 3), rep("1986", 3))
column2 <- gl(3, 1, 9, labels=c("Roach", "Green", "Sucker"))
column3 <- c(20, 25, 10, 70, 85, 30, 10, 65, 70)
d <- data.frame(column1=column1, column2=column2, column3=column3)
require(lattice)
barchart(column3 ~ column1, groups=column2, d, auto.key = list(columns = 3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    column1 <- c(rep("1984", 3), rep("1985", 3), rep("1986", 3))
 column2 <- gl(3, 1, 9, labels=c("Roach", "Green", "Sucker"))
column3 <- c(20, 25, 10, 70, 85, 30, 10, 65, 70)
d <- data.frame(column1=column1, column2=column2, column3=column3)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=column1, y=column3, fill=column2)) + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]